# CIDER inspector unable to refresh a modified atom

Tags: debugging, clojure, cider

With the CIDER inspector I'm able to view the contents of an atom. I can do <kbd>C-u C-u C-c M-i</kbd> and input the atom with an `@` prefix and the value displays correctly. Now, if I keep the inspector window open and modify the atom, then upon refreshing (<kbd>g</kbd>) I would expect the modify value to appear. However, this is not the case.

Which made me think... At the top of the inspector window I can see the following type information: `Class: clojure.lang.PersistentVector`. So probably what gets passed to the inspector is the raw value *after* dereferencing the atom, i.e. the inspector does not know it's dealing with an atom.

Am I missing something important here? I mean, shouldn't the correct behavior be for the inspector to deal with the whole extent of inspected entity - in this case to recognize the *atomicity* of passed expression?